# Allowing Google to index auto generated sub domains

Tags: google-index, multi-subdomains

I have a web application where each new customer using the application has their own unique subdomain.  This allows them to link to the products they create on our site.

If my website is `www.example.com` then my customers get the domain `customer.example.com`.  These subdomains are auto generated when the customer sets up their account.

What can I do so that Google will index these subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Google will find sites fairly quickly. I actually discovered that Google may be watching registration/DNS entries and finding sites within hours. They found one of my sites, spidered it, indexed it, and I saw search traffic within about 2 hours! You may not need to do anything. If you want to tell Google about the site, link to the sub-domain from the parent domain. That is the easiest way. Find an appropriate page that Google pays attention to- that is, spiders fairly often. About, Contact, and the like are not generally spidered often, but perhaps you can create a page just for this purpose. Your choice. You do not need a sitemap on each sub-domain or anything else new. That is backwards logic. Modifying the sub-domain will not speed up discovery of the sub-domain.

Comment: Google probably uses ways to read new registrations. Indeed. But as far as I know there is no way to read all the extensions defined in a DNS file. This means what you are talking about won't work because in the OP case he does not make new registrations each time. Only a DNS change.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke I respect what you are saying. I was not suggesting that was the case for the OP but rather illustrating that Google is aggressive in discovering new sites these days. BTW- Google and others have agreements with registrars and DNS operators such as Network Solution for updates to their database. I used GoDaddy to register my one site and there is no rational way that Google could have known about my site instantly without GoDaddy telling them. Spidered, indexed and searchable within 2 hours of registration is incredible!

Answer (score 0):

Make a sitemap with those in it, add google analytics, make a link to it from the `www`. Just linkbuilding-101 really.

Comment: You cannot do that. You have to have one sitemap.xml file per website. (one domain name per sitemap.xml) At least as far as I know you cannot mix multiple URL in a single sitemap.xml file.

Comment: I believe you can link websites not even related to you. Not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, Google is really good at finding new websites really quickly. That being said, if you want to make sure that it gets picked up readily and your web system generates a sitemap.xml file, then you can submit the file using the following URL (PHP code):

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=" . $sitemapUrl;
```

Full PHP script on how to use curl to submit the sitemap to Google:

> http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2013/01/script-automatically-submit-sitemap-google-bing-yahoo-ask-etc/

Just make sure you do not submit a sitemap more than once a day. If you submit the same too many times, Google is likely to block your IP address.